# How to calculate ECDH shared secret in Swift to match the one generated in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, swift, ecdh

I am generating ECDH shared secret in NodeJS and I want to generate the same shared secret in Swift (iOS). I need it to work for keys generated with `secp256k1` and `secp224r1` curves.

In NodeJS my code looks like this:

```js
import crypto from 'node:crypto'

const keyPair2 = {
    privateKey: Buffer.from(
      'iUfaS6XxDCOS65sGqeunCQJR4045pTA3H4cCcYqfLpg',
      'base64'
    ),
    publicKey: Buffer.from(
      'BJPPEL/HhVR4Yv8qyKT/1A8rcRhmP8aXBKCikXeShNhjWWWKjDuKt9zco7Flt9l14uJW1lt2kCIjb8e64wDW5Sg=',
      'base64'
    ),
  }

  const ecdh1 = crypto.createECDH('secp256k1')
  ecdh1.setPrivateKey(keyPair1.privateKey)
  const sharedSecret1 = ecdh1.computeSecret(keyPair2.publicKey)

  const ecdh2 = crypto.createECDH('secp256k1')
  ecdh2.setPrivateKey(keyPair2.privateKey)
  const sharedSecret2 = ecdh2.computeSecret(keyPair1.publicKey)

  // sharedSecret1 and sharedSecret2 are the same: "/SW/mVsgNNqXq42c6n6RsxPHdX1nJn3srPJ61IN1fPE="
```

Now, in Swift I looked into [SwiftEEC](https://github.com/leif-ibsen/SwiftECC) library. And so far I have come up with the following:

```swift
import SwiftECC

func base64ToPrivateKey(x: String) throws -> ECPrivateKey? {
    if let data = Data(base64Encoded: x) {
        let bytes = [UInt8](data)
        let bInt = BInt(magnitude: bytes)
        return try ECPrivateKey(domain: domain, s: bInt)
    }
    
    return nil
}

func base64ToPublicKey(x: String) throws -> ECPublicKey? {
    if let data = Data(base64Encoded: x) {
        let bytes = [UInt8](data)
        let withoutPrefix = bytes.dropFirst()
        let half = withoutPrefix.count / 2
        let x = [UInt8](withoutPrefix.prefix(half))
        let y = [UInt8](withoutPrefix.suffix(half))
        return try ECPublicKey(domain: domain, w: Point(BInt(magnitude: x), BInt(magnitude: y)))
    }
    return nil
}

let myPrivateKey = try base64ToPrivateKey(x: "DmuxAqe2H4Ntyuc9Vex/Zbl4+w5/sdPWBBlmJqU+pjs=")!
let otherSidePublickey = try base64ToPublicKey(x: "BJPPEL/HhVR4Yv8qyKT/1A8rcRhmP8aXBKCikXeShNhjWWWKjDuKt9zco7Flt9l14uJW1lt2kCIjb8e64wDW5Sg=")!

let sharedSecret = try myPrivateKey.keyAgreement(
    pubKey: otherSidePublickey,
    length: 32,
    // The problem is the next line. In node there is no option to specify message digest. 
    // Shared secret does not match with the one generated in node no matter what I 
    // put here.
    md: .SHA2_224,
    sharedInfo: []
)

// outputs: "myXnNz+5YDdMHJ4N1AMwsXqpxf/SJy2h0Kzo1Qw9yk8="
print(Data(sharedKey).base64EncodedString())
```

Is there a way how to do the same operation that can be done with Node in Swift? It seems like keyAgreement function is calculating some other value then shared secret, but there is no other function in SwiftECC that calculates some kind of shared value between the keys.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I have created a [pull request](https://github.com/leif-ibsen/SwiftECC/pull/40) to SwiftECC to add function that does allow you to generate shared secret without hashing it